# Netsh trace vs PEF trace cmdlets vs NetEvent cmdlets

Tags: powershell, traffic, packet-capture, filtering, packet-sniffer

I am playing with capturing my network traffic and came across two different MS commandline tools that allow doing this:

1. a well-known [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx) tool, recently equipped with powerful [capture switch](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/netsh-traceuse-it/)
2. a brand-new [PEF Framework](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj714800.aspx) that is shipped together with MS Message Analyzer.

MS Analyzer is a tool that covers all my requirements in traffic analyzing, however it does have one disadvantage: it is very **resource-greedy**. 
So I decided to switch to commandline tools in my everyday work and came to the above two options.

As it stated in PS PEF cmdlets documentation, [PEF commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168858.aspx) mainly follow Message Analyzer functionality which makes it very powerful and configurable. However, **netsh trace capture** has [very extended](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878517(v=ws.10).aspx) syntax too and I am stuck upon choosing the right tool.

Dear admin gurus, does anybody have experience with both tools and can give reasoned advice on the subject:

- Do PEF commands has exactly the same features as Message Analyzer?
- If so, is there any advantage in using netsh over PEF? Performance?
- Any limitations in both  of them?

**UPD:** For now the only distinction I was able to find between them is that netsh trace doesn't support IP-subnetting specification (in CIDR or whatever) and that's it. I see no other differences: both of them support the same filters, the same providers (incl. ETW) and so on...

**UPD2:** I also discovered [Network Event Packet Capture cmdlets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/10/12/packet-sniffing-with-powershell-getting-started/) just now and it seems they do exactly the same. Completely confused now ((

Comment: Cool... wonder which gurus of these will answer!!